# scrollViewDidEndDecelerating not executing

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I can't seem to get scrollViewDidEndDecelerating called.
I have a scrollView with 2 Views inside. Now I need it to set a value to a label in the first view when the scrollview is finished scrolling to the second view.

Header File:

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController
{
   UIScrollView *scrollView;
   UIView *view1;
   UIView *view2;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
```

Implementation File:

```
@synthesize scrollView, view1, view2;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.view1=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
   self.view2=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];

   [self.scrollView addSubView:self.view1];
   [self.scrollView addSubView:self.view2];

   self.scrollView.bounces=NO;
   self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(640,460);
   [self.scrollView setShowHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
   [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416) animated:NO];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIView *)scrollView
{
   lbl.text=@"0";
}
```

I don't see anything wrong, it should be working. Can someone help me out? Would appreciate it.

Comment: did you set the scrollview delegate?

Comment: By the looks of it, he didn't.

Comment: Hm, no I didn't add anything to the delegate file.
How would I set it? Thanks :)

Comment: To make matters more fun: The only delegate method that gets called by programmatic scrolling with animated:NO is `-scrollViewDidScroll:`, and only if scrolling took place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do:

Header File:

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> //promise that you'll act as scrollView's delegate
{
   UIScrollView *scrollView;
   UIView *view1;
   UIView *view2;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
```

Implementation File:

```
@synthesize scrollView, view1, view2;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.view1=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
   self.view2=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];

   [self.scrollView addSubView:self.view1];
   [self.scrollView addSubView:self.view2];

   self.scrollView.bounces=NO;
   self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(640,460);
   [self.scrollView setShowHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
   [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416) animated:NO];
   [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];//Set delegate
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIView *)scrollView
{
   lbl.text=@"0";
}
```

Comment: Hey one last thing, how would I check the x position of view2?

Comment: you can access it via it's frame property: int x-pos=view2.frame.origin.x; 
It'd work I guess and that's what you wanted right?

Answer (score 40):

scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is not called if the user is scrolling slowly (i.e. the scroll view does not continue to scroll on touch up). In that case the delegate calls scrollViewDidEndDragging. So to do something when the user has stopped scrolling and the scrollview has stopped you can combine them:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
  if !decelerate {
     endOfScroll()
  }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  endOfScroll()
}

func endOfScroll() {
  //The user finished scrolling
}
```

In Objective-C

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
   if(!decelerate) [self endOfScroll];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
  [self endOfScroll];
}

-(void)endOfScroll{
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: So the scrollview could end without decelerating. That's why the parameter 'decelerate' exists!

Answer (score 5):

Either connect the delegate property of the scrollview to the File's Owner object in Interface Builder or just set the delegate manually in your ViewController's ViewDidLoad.

```
scrollview.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

When scrolling `UIScrollView` **programmatically**, the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is not called , but you can still use the `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` delegate function as a substitude for that, however there are some limitations stated in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619379-scrollviewdidendscrollinganimati) :

> The scroll view calls this method at the end of its implementations of the setContentOffset(*:animated:) and scrollRectToVisible(*:animated:) methods, but only if animations are requested.

Therefore if you are not using default `animated:true`, but rather animating scrolling with custom `UIView.animate` animation (for example to change scrolling speed) , the only delegate method that still executes is `scrollViewDidScroll`