# Add scrollable button to scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I want to scroll five buttons inside a scrollview.  When the user stops dragging a button it should move on to the next button.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var categoryArr = ["Jack","Mark","Down","Bill","Steve"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(CGSizeMake(150,categoryScrollView.frame.size.height), buttonCount: 5)
        categoryScrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
        categoryScrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)
        categoryScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        categoryScrollView.delegate = self
        categoryScrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        categoryScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default
    }


func colorButtonsView(buttonSize:CGSize, buttonCount:Int) -> UIView {
        let buttonView = UIView()
        buttonView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0)
        let padding = CGSizeMake(10, 10)
        buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(buttonCount)
        var buttonPosition = CGPointMake(padding.width * 0.5, padding.height)
        let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width
        for i in 0...(buttonCount - 1)  {
            var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as! UIButton
            button.frame.size = buttonSize
            button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
            buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
            button.setTitle(categoryArr[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
        }
        return buttonView
    }
}
extension ViewController:UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let index = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        print(index)
    }
}
```

The scrollview scrolls well.. but only twice.  It Doesn't scroll to next Button.  What should I do?

Comment: Use the code in my answer. It works fine for me and scrolls one button at a time in horizontal direction

Comment: Are you using Autolayout?

Answer (score 8):

```
func setContentOffset(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    let numOfItems = itemCount  // 5
    let stopOver = scrollView.contentSize.width / CGFloat(numOfItems)
    let x = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / stopOver) * stopOver
    
    guard x >= 0 && x <= scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.width else {
        return
    }
    
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(x, scrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: true)
}
```

---

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
        setContentOffset(scrollView)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    
        guard !decelerate else {
            return
        }
    
        setContentOffset(scrollView)
    }
}
```

Also made a demo project in Github 
 https://github.com/rishi420/ScrollViewCustomPaging

---

### Update:

Trying to consider for the scrolling velocity when user endDragging.

```
var velocityX = CGFloat(0.0)
```

.

```
func setContentOffset(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    let numOfItems = itemCount
    let stopOver = scrollView.contentSize.width / CGFloat(numOfItems)
    var x = round((scrollView.contentOffset.x + (velocityX * 150)) / stopOver) * stopOver // 150 is for test. Change it for your liking
    
    x = max(0, min(x, scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.width))
    
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(x, scrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: true)
}
```

.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
{
    velocityX = velocity.x
}
```

Comment: works ok..but how do i find the index? the one right now visible

Comment: `round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / stopOver)`

Comment: what should i do if i want the animation while scrolling fast? and the last one doesnot seem to be confusing either active or not?

Comment: tried `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, it is fast but animation does not look good. you can try yourself. Instead of `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating` call the method from `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`

Comment: another way could be using `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity`. If velocity is higher may be increase index count. so scrollView scrolls more and stop at the next index.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a UITableView instead of UIScrollView and making the tableview's size equal to size of button you want. 
Then add the button to its cell.
Enable the UITableView's **"Paging"**

This will help you better to manage content i.e. buttons more conveniently as you are can pass the array of buttons to the tableview and manage in its **cellForAtIndex** method.

Comment: why tableview instead of collection view? and i dont think it works if i want to add two button in same cell ?

Answer (score 0):

After you calculate the button index in your `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating()` method, simply call `scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated:)` with the frame of the button at that index.

Comment: i cant really calculate the index..it only shows two index 0.0 and 1.0 ..i want a mechanism that will display five index for five buttons right?

Answer (score 0):

The `UIScrollView` does not always decelerate. You can use the approach from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13067444, or use `targetContentOffset` from `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this modified code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var categoryScrollView: UIScrollView!
var categoryArr = ["Jack","Mark","Down","Bill","Steve"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(CGSizeMake(categoryScrollView.frame.size.width / 3 ,categoryScrollView.frame.size.height), buttonCount: 5)
    categoryScrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
    categoryScrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)
    categoryScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    categoryScrollView.delegate = self
    categoryScrollView.pagingEnabled = false
    categoryScrollView.bounces = false
    categoryScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default
}


func colorButtonsView(buttonSize:CGSize, buttonCount:Int) -> UIView {
    let buttonView = UIView()
    buttonView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0)
    let padding = CGSizeMake(10, 10)
    buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(buttonCount)
    var buttonPosition = CGPointMake(padding.width * 0.5, padding.height)
    let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width
    for i in 0...(buttonCount - 1)  {
        let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button.frame.size = buttonSize
        button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
        buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
        button.setTitle(categoryArr[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttonView.addSubview(button)
    }
    return buttonView
}
```

}

```
extension ViewController:UIScrollViewDelegate{

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let buttonWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width / 3
        let index = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / buttonWidth)
        targetContentOffset.memory.x = index*buttonWidth + index*10
    }

}
```

Comment: i dont see the change?

Comment: This line  :     let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(categoryScrollView.frame.size, buttonCount: 5)

Comment: it works but not as expected..if i want button widht as 1/3 of the categoryScrollView frame

Answer (score 0):

Fine tuned Aruna's code a bit. Set some background colors for easy debugging to see that the expected behaviour is obtained.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var categoryArr = ["Jack","Mark","Down","Bill","Steve"]
    var buttonColors = [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.magentaColor()]
    let kPadding:CGFloat = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let buttonSize = CGSizeMake(categoryScrollView.bounds.size.width/2, categoryScrollView.bounds.size.height/2)//hal

        let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(buttonSize, buttonCount: 5)
        categoryScrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
        categoryScrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)
        categoryScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        categoryScrollView.delegate = self
        categoryScrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        categoryScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default
        categoryScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    }


    func colorButtonsView(buttonSize:CGSize, buttonCount:Int) -> UIView {
        let buttonView = UIView()
        buttonView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0)
        let padding = CGSizeMake(kPadding, kPadding)
        buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(buttonCount)
        var buttonPosition = CGPointMake(0, padding.height)
        let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width
        for i in 0...(buttonCount - 1)  {
            let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
            button.frame.size = buttonSize
            button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
            buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
            button.setTitle(categoryArr[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.backgroundColor = buttonColors[i]
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
        }
        buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return buttonView
    }
}
extension ViewController:UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let index = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        print(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but the indexing is not proper...as there are 5 buttons but index from 0 to 3